# Get all text after a string until next occurrence of the string?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

How can i get all the text after every occurrence of a string for example, I have to following text:

```
commonstring
text and more text and more
random text that may or may 
not be on multiple lines
commonstring
more random text that
will be after the common string
```

How can I make that into an array of

```
{ "text and more text and more random text that may or may not be on multiple lines", "more random text that will be after the common string" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bwe3zdy.aspx) overload:

```
string[] parts = s.Split(new[] { "commonstring" }, int.MaxValue, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: I think that there may be a problem with my regex mind checking this for me? `ÿÿÿÿ  [..]ÿÿÿÿ[*]` should be `ÿÿÿÿ  Ùÿÿÿÿrandom.cfg` or `ÿÿÿÿ  5ÿÿÿÿanotherrandom.cfg` or `ÿÿÿÿ /5ÿÿÿÿandanotherrandom.cfg`

Comment: Er... sorry, I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: Using regex I want to make a string that would work if, for example the `ÿÿÿÿ Ùÿÿÿÿrandom.cfg` had a `a` instead of a `Ù` and `hello.cfg` instead of `random.cfg`

Comment: you don't need a regex for that, just use the code above and replace "commonstring" with "ÿÿÿÿ"

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use Regex.Split:

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(inputString, @"commonstring");
```